# Rails bootstrap erb collection_check_boxes not selecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the model `Game` that represents games. Each game can have related games, so I have another model `Related Games` so `Game.related_games` holds the related games for that game.

The `related_games` model structure is `[game_id, name]` where `game_id` is the game's id the relation is linked to, and `name` is the name of the game that is related to that game.

Now when I display the erb like this:

```
f.collection_check_boxes :related_games, Game.all, :id, :name
```

The related games will not be selected, like its empty, while the game has related games.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think your models are incorrect (or I did not understand your use case). Your RelatedGame model has a game_id and a name. What does this name represent? If this name is the one for the game_id, it is unnecessary (you have the name through the link game_id). If it is the name of another game, you really should have another game_id.

I believe your models should be:

Model Similarity (or another name, this is your RelatedGame, with some changes)

```
class Similarity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game1, :foreign_key => 'game1_id', :class_name => "Game"
  belongs_to :game2, :foreign_key => 'game2_id', :class_name => "Game"
end
```

Model Game

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :similarities1, :class_name => "Similarity", :foreign_key => "game1_id"
  has_many :similarities2, :class_name => "Similarity", :foreign_key => "game2_id"

  has_many :similar_games, :through => :similarities1, source: "Game"
  has_many :inverse_similar_games, :through => :similarities2, source: "Game"

  def all_similar_games
    (similar_games + inverse_similar_games).uniq
  end
end
```

Games Controller

```
def edit
  # The game to edit
  @game = Game.find_by(id: params[:id])

  # The relation table (similarity) where this game is the game1
  @related = @game.similarities1

  # The games related to this game (all games linked by game2 in the similarities relation, where this game is game1)
  @similar_games = @game.similar_games

  # All games related to this one through similarity, whether through game1 or game2
  @all_similar_games = @game.all_similar_games
end
```

In the view:

```
<h1>@game.name</h1>
<% form_for @game do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :name %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :similar_game_ids, Game.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:related_game_ids` instead of `:related_games`.

`f.collection_check_boxes :related_game_ids, Game.all, :id, :name`

*Don't forget to permit `:related_game_ids` in your controller.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your model look like if your relations ok and model formatted properly then

Try the following

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :game_ids, Game.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
<% end %>
```

and the controller `strong parameters` use like below

```
game_ids: []
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you put in your controller that related_games accepts a hash of ids?

**game_controller.rb**

```
private
def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(
          //fields_of_game,               
          related_game_ids: []
        )
    end
```

in you form

**games/_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "game[related_game_ids][]", nil %>
        <% Related_Games.all.each do |r_games| %>

              <%= check_box_tag "game[related_game_ids][]", r_games.id, @game.related_game_id.include?(r_game.id), id: dom_id(r_game) %>
              <%= label_tag dom_id(r_game), r_game.name %> <br>

        <% end %>
```

in your model **game.rb**
did you put the association?
Something like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :related_games
def related_games_attributes=(related_game_attributes)
    related_game_attributes.values.each do |related_game_attribute|
      related_game = Related_Games.find_or_create_by(related_game)
      self.related_game << related_game 
    end
  end
```